# Yii2 Nav Bar add images in menu items

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Is it possible to add images in Yii2 Bootstrap Nav Bar menu items?
In  [official doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-navbar.html) I haven't found any option.

I want to show images instead of Label text!

Nav Bar code is.

```
<?php
    NavBar::begin([
        'brandLabel' => 'My Company',
        'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
        ],
    ]);

   $menuItems = [];

   $menuItems[] = [
            'label' => Yii::t('app','Language'),
            'items' => [
                [
                  'label' => 'English', 
                  'url' => ['site/language','set'=>'en'],
                ],

                '<li class="divider"></li>',

                [
                  'label' => 'Danmark',
                  'url' => ['site/language','set'=>'da'],
                ],

              ],
      ];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if an icon you can use icon

```
   $menuItems[] = [
        'label' => Yii::t('app','Language'),
        'items' => [
            [
              'label' => 'English', 
              'url' => ['site/language','set'=>'en'],
              'icon'=> 'cog',
            ],
```

if an img  and the html code in label

```
  $menuItems[] = [
        'label' => Yii::t('app','Language'),
        'items' => [
            [
              'label' => '<img src="smiley.gif" ><span>sample</span>', 
              'url' => ['site/language','set'=>'en'],
            ],
```

I use

```
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
```

and you should set the 'encodeLabels' => false,

```
        echo Nav::widget([
            'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
            'items' => $menuItems,
            'encodeLabels' => false,
        ]);
```

Comment: 'label' => '<img src="smiley.gif" ><span>sample</span>',  I tied this but it shows the html as it is `<img src="smiley.gif" ><span>sample</span>`

Comment: strange  this work fo for me   ..  I use navbar widget

Comment: Can you please post your nav bar code! may be you have set some extra options.

Comment: I  have update the answer ..  use encodeLabels => false;

Comment: `encodeLabels => false;` is working for me, thank you very much. what actually it does?

Comment: All the label (and i general all output) are encode in Yii2  for avoid injection of code  .. so the content of a label is wrapped for avoid the render of html .. using encodeLabels => false, you tell to the framework the in this case you want explicitally pass html code for a proper render .. hope the explanation is clear ..

Comment: there isnt any `icon` property for `items` that you are setting in the first code example. can you confirm?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam... your  comment is not clear to me.. .. if you set the image using html and encodeLabels => false  .. why set the icon ..  should be unuseful or in conflict ..  with the html code  .. in label

Comment: you cannot set an `icon` property anyway, because there isnt any for the `items` that is what i wanted to say.

Answer (score 5):

Add 'encodeLabels' => false, as a attribute for Nav::widget. Or else it will not convert the code to HTML and it will consider it as string and it will display as it is given inside the label.

```
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-left'],
    'encodeLabels' => false,
    'items' => [
        [
            'label' => '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>', 
            'url' => ['/site/dashboard'],
        ],
    ] // Close of items
    ]); // Close of Nav::Widget.
```

Answer (score 3):

Add an image tag to the 'brandLabel' setting:

```
NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => '<img id="logo" src="/img/logo.svg" alt="logo">',
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar',
    ],
]);
```